# wxPython wait for dialog response before continuing

Tags: python, dialog, wxpython, listener

I created a dialog that requires the user to click on a button to proceed (eg. "Are you sure you want to do this?") and uses a listener to wait for the response

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub  
...  
pub.subscribe(self.my_listener, "my_listener")
```

and a function to set a variable once the response is clicked on.

```
def my_listener(self, message):
    if message == 'proceed':
        self.proceed = True
    else:
        self.proceed = False
```

The main body of my code looks like:

```
self.proceed = False       # Make sure it's false initially
launch_verify_dialog()     # Launch the dialog
if self.proceed:
    # DO STUFF
else:
    print 'NARF!'
```

Now, the issue is that when this runs, the code runs through the "if self.proceed" if statement and prints "NARF!" immediately, before I have a chance to respond to the dialog. Why does this happen and how can I wait for a response to the dialog before continuing?

I've tried putting a loop in front of the if statement to wait for a response, but that just crashes the program, and I've verified that the listener works and sets the self.proceed variable correctly.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use a dialog instead of a frame and use `dlg.ShowModal()`

or if you simply want to ask a simple yes/no question

```
if wx.MessageBox("Are You Sure?","Checking",wx.YES_NO) == wx.YES:
   print ("User Clicked Yes")
else:
   print ("User did not click yes (clicked No or closed)")
```

if you need more complicated thing

```
class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
       wx.Dialog.__init__(self,None,-1,"A Title")
       wx.StaticText(self,-1,"Some Text!")
       b = wx.Button(self,-1,"Click",pos=(100,100))
       b.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)
     def OnClick(self,evt):
       pub.sendMessage("whatever")
       self.Destroy()

 MyDialog().ShowModal()
 #will not continue until MyDialog Closes...
```